# Installed Qt5.15 LTS (5.15.7), debug DLLs missing/not installed

Tags: qt, qt5

I used the online installer to install Qt 5.15.7.

Running my application in Release mode from Qt Creator worked fine.

When I attempted to run it in Debug mode, I get the following System Error dialog:

[image: System Error Dialog]

I searched my bin directory (C:\Qt\5.15.7\mingw81_32\bin) for Qt5Cored.dll, but it's completely missing any and all DLL files:

[image: Qt 5.15.7 mingw81_32 bin directory]

Does anyone know where/how to install the debug dll files for Qt?

Answer (score 0):

There is a chance that they are not available for non-commercial license, although if you have it just look for debug symbols in Qt installer as they might be distributed separatelly.